# Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.PhoneNumberKit' is correct

Tags: ios, cocoapods, phonenumberkit

I installed PhoneNumberKit by adding

> pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 2.6'
>   to the podFile and

running pod install

after that my app builds fine but when i archive the app for deployment i

get error

> No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.PhoneNumberKit' is correct.

Comment: Check the bundle identifier for your app target. You seem to have ended up with the phone number kit placeholder bundle id.

Comment: @Paulw11 i am relatively new to ios development i am finding it hard to make sense of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

After much search none of the solution work for me but this and it is really simple.

step 1 open  info.plist in TextEdit

step 2 find CFBundlePackageType

step 3 set the value to APPL like 
APPL

step 4 clean, archive and resubmit your project

hope it helps.